# How to create a new column with column values based on the shared column across 2 Dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, join, dataframe, merge

Given the dataframes `df` and `df2`:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[1,'a','b'], [1, 'c', 'd'], 
                       [2, 'c', 'd'], [1, 'f', 'o'], 
                       [2, 'b', 'a']], columns=['x', 'y', 'z'])

>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 'apple'], [2, 'orange'], 
                        [3, 'pear']], columns=['x', 'fruit'])

>>> df
   x  y  z
0  1  a  b
1  1  c  d
2  2  c  d
3  1  f  o
4  2  b  a

>>> df2
   x   fruit
0  1   apple
1  2  orange
2  3    pear
```

**How to create a new column with the `fruit` column values based on the shared `x` column?**

Desired output:

```
>>> df
   x  y  z   fruit
0  1  a  b   apple
1  1  c  d   apple
2  2  c  d  orange
3  1  f  o   apple
4  2  b  a  orange
```

I've tried this, it works but I'm sure there's a simpler way to do this:

```
>>> df['fruit'] = [list(df2[df2['x'] == row['x']]['fruit'])[0] for idx, row in df.iterrows()]
>>> df
   x  y  z   fruit
0  1  a  b   apple
1  1  c  d   apple
2  2  c  d  orange
3  1  f  o   apple
4  2  b  a  orange
```

---

Note that the Dataframes above are unindexed. If the dataframes were indexed, the tried method won't work:

```
>>> df = df.set_index('x')
>>> df2 = df2.set_index('x')
>>> df
   y  z   fruit
x              
1  a  b   apple
1  c  d   apple
2  c  d  orange
1  f  o   apple
2  b  a  orange
>>> df2
    fruit
x        
1   apple
2  orange
3    pear
>>> df['fruit'] = [list(df2[df2['x'] == row['x']]['fruit'])[0] for idx, row in df.iterrows()]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2062, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_column(key)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2069, in _getitem_column
    return self._get_item_cache(key)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 1534, in _get_item_cache
    values = self._data.get(item)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 3590, in get
    loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2395, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 132, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/_libs/index.c:5239)
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 154, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/_libs/index.c:5085)
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1207, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/_libs/hashtable.c:20405)
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1215, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/_libs/hashtable.c:20359)
KeyError: 'x'
```

Comment: Simply merge on `x` column: `pd.merge(df, df2, on='x')`

Comment: For exactily same order `df.merge(df2, how='left')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html#pandas-dataframe-merge):

```
df.merge(df2, on='x')
```

Output:

```
   x  y  z   fruit
0  1  a  b   apple
1  1  c  d   apple
2  1  f  o   apple
3  2  c  d  orange
4  2  b  a  orange
```

Answer (score 4):

Or using `map`

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,'a','b'], [1, 'c', 'd'],
                           [2, 'c', 'd'], [1, 'f', 'o'],
                           [2, 'b', 'a']], columns=['x', 'y', 'z'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 'apple'], [2, 'orange'],
                        [3, 'pear']], columns=['x', 'fruit'])

df['fruit']=df.x.map(df2.set_index('x').fruit)


df
Out[257]: 
   x  y  z   fruit
0  1  a  b   apple
1  1  c  d   apple
2  2  c  d  orange
3  1  f  o   apple
4  2  b  a  orange
```

Assuming you already done with `set_index()` merge by index then ~

```
df = df.set_index('x')
df2 = df2.set_index('x')

df.merge(df2,left_index=True,right_index=True)

Out[260]: 
   y  z   fruit
x              
1  a  b   apple
1  c  d   apple
1  f  o   apple
2  c  d  orange
2  b  a  orange
```

Answer (score 1):

For completeness

```
df.join(df2.set_index('x'), on='x')

   x  y  z   fruit
0  1  a  b   apple
1  1  c  d   apple
2  2  c  d  orange
3  1  f  o   apple
4  2  b  a  orange
```